# Postgresql syntax error at or near "("

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I trying to write some condition to pull out objects from database:

```
Page.where(published: true).where("`published_at` <= current_date()").where("`publication_end` IS NULL OR `publication_end` > current_date()")
```

When i enter it in the rails console i have the following error:

```
 SELECT "pages".* FROM "pages" WHERE "pages"."published" = 't' AND (`published_at` <= current_date()) AND (`publication_end` IS NULL OR `publication_end` > current_date())
PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "("
LINE 1: ...blished" = 't' AND (`published_at` <= current_date()) AND (`...
                                                             ^
: SELECT "pages".* FROM "pages"  WHERE "pages"."published" = 't' AND (`published_at` <= current_date()) AND (`publication_end` IS NULL OR `publication_end` > current_date())
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "("
LINE 1: ...blished" = 't' AND (`published_at` <= current_date()) AND (`...
                                                             ^
: SELECT "pages".* FROM "pages"  WHERE "pages"."published" = 't' AND (`published_at` <= current_date()) AND (`publication_end` IS NULL OR `publication_end` > current_date())
```

I,m Using Postgresql
Please help.

Comment: Did you simply try to remove the `()` after `current_date`?

Comment: `current_date` does not have the trailing "()", though "now()" does.

Comment: I hope those backticks are part of the ActiveRecord's syntax and not something that's sent to Postgres.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i write:

```
Page.where(published: true).where("published_at <= current_date").where("publication_end IS NULL OR publication_end > current_date")
```

and now i ok

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Remove the parentheses:

```
# select current_date();
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "("
LINE 1: select current_date();  

# select current_date;
    date
------------
 2014-02-19
(1 row)
```

Comment: By way of explanation: `current_date` is a special SQL keyword specified in the ANSI SQL standard. It acts like a function that takes zero arguments, but unlike a function its syntax doesn't require or allow parentheses. Yet another example of the SQL standards committee making up weird syntax for fun.